# Store files in sequential file numbers

Tags: perl

I want to open a `data(n).txt` file (in a directory with already existing `data(n).txt` files, e.g.: `data0001.txt`, `data0002.txt`, `data0003.txt`).

After printing some data in this (new) file, I want to store this new file with a sequential file number (in this example: `data0004.txt`).

This code only creates the `data0001.txt` file, and overwrites its content:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl    
open (DATEI, ">>data0001.txt") or die $!;
   print DATEI "this is a test";
close (DATEI);
```

Comment: That code does not overwrite the content. `>>` means append mode, not overwrite.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for one of those logfile rotation modules.

Comment: Thx, you are right  > is the right code to overwrite

Answer (score 3):

In order to name a file as described, with a number one larger than the largest number in an existing filename, we need to first read the directory and find out what the highest number in a filename is.  Then we can write our new file, using `sprintf` to format the number into a four-character string in its filename

One way to do this

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use List::Util qw(max);

# Submit directory on the command line or use the one where this script is    
my $dir = shift // $RealBin;

my @files = glob "$dir/data*txt";

my $max_num = max map { /data([0-9]{4})\.txt/ } @files;

my $next_file_name = "$dir/" . 'data' . sprintf("%04d", $max_num+1) . '.txt';

open my $fh, '>', $next_file_name or die "Can't open $next_file_name: $!";

say $fh "Writing to the next file $next_file_name";

close $fh or warn "Error writing to $next_file_name: $!"
```

This is a sketch, which can be worked into a more rounded and flexible program, depending on your requirements.

Documentation, mostly in order of appearance: [FindBin](https://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin), [List::Util::max](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#max), [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob), [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map), [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) (regular expressions "tutorial" introduction), [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf), [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open), [close](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close).

While I use `glob` to read entries from a directory consider loading [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Glob) with

```
use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';
```

and then for `glob` a routine from this module is used, which has some advantages.

The mode `>>` used in the question's code is for opening a file for append (and won't overwrite).  But since the description repeatedly talks about writing a "new file" I take that to be the question.  See `open` for use of `>>`, if you actually want to write (append) to an existing file.

---

Note on the tools used: The `map` and regex in this list are rounded tools which get used a lot, and the `List::Util` library has basic utilities for daily work.  I recommend getting well acquainted with them.  The regex, though, is a large and complex tool, practically a language in its own right, which takes time to learn well. But even its basics are very useful and it's hard to work without it.

Comment: I tried this basic sketch, but I always only get overwritten the file data0001.txt

Comment: We can't see what you tried, so there's no way to help. Add to your answer a minimal , complete script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Gerd  "_I always only get overwritten the file data0001.txt_"  --  I don't see how that can happen.  What files do you have in that directory?  What program do you run -- is it _exactly_ the code from this answer, copied into a program?  If not, can you add to the end of the question the code you actually run?  (The question does mention overwriting but yuo don't show the code that does that.  What you do show can't overwrite anything?)

Comment: @Bork, thanks with "data0001.txt" in the current directory it works.